# Weird characters on linux terminal

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, editor

I'm getting weird characheters on my linux terminal.

Kindly check the below sample screenshot.

[image]

Kindly suggest how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. What is the LANG environment variable set to?

Try

```
export LANG=iso-8859-1 # or UTF-8 etc
```

Comment: `LANG` was set to `en_US.UTF-8`. Changing it to `iso-8859-1` or `UTF-8`, solved the problem. Thanks +1 :)